# MVC Razor inline html

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

How may I add HTML inside Razor tags?

I would like to add a DIV tag to my Html.ActionLink

```
  @if (Model == null)
  {
    @:<div class="m_button_wrapper">
      @Html.ActionLink("Stats", "Statistic", new { id = -1 });
    @:</div>
    @:<div class="m_button_wrapper">
      @Html.ActionLink("Result", "Result", new { id = -1 });
    @:</div>
  }
  else
  {
    @:<div class="m_button_wrapper">
      @Html.ActionLink("Stats", "Statistic", new { id = Model.id });
    @:</div>
    @:<div class="m_button_wrapper">
      @Html.ActionLink("Result", "Result", new { id = Model.id });
    @:</div>
  }
```

The DIV tags are not being generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@if (Model == null)
{
<div class="m_button_wrapper">
  @Html.ActionLink("Stats", "Statistic", new { id = -1 });
</div>
<div class="m_button_wrapper">
  @Html.ActionLink("Result", "Result", new { id = -1 });
</div>
}
else
{
<div class="m_button_wrapper">
  @Html.ActionLink("Stats", "Statistic", new { id = Model.id });
</div>
<div class="m_button_wrapper">
  @Html.ActionLink("Result", "Result", new { id = Model.id });
</div>
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 @if (Model == null)
  {
    <div class="m_button_wrapper">
      @Html.ActionLink("Stats", "Statistic", new { id = -1 });
    </div>
    <div class="m_button_wrapper">
      @Html.ActionLink("Result", "Result", new { id = -1 });
    </div>
  }
  else
  {
    <div class="m_button_wrapper">
      @Html.ActionLink("Stats", "Statistic", new { id = Model.id });
    </div>
    <div class="m_button_wrapper">
      @Html.ActionLink("Result", "Result", new { id = Model.id });
    </div>
  }
```

You don't have to put @ everywhere - Razor parser is smart enough to match { with }.